# Use multiple plugins with parameters in VueJS

Tags: vue.js, plugins

Let say I have 2 plugins I want to use:

`Bootstrap-Vue` & `Vue Analytics`

I would import like so

```
import BootstrapVue from 'bootstrap-vue'
import VueAnalytics from 'vue-analytics'
```

How would I use them if one has parameters?

Is this correct?

```
Vue.use(BootstrapVue, VueAnalytics, {
    id: 'UA-12345678-9'
});
```

Comment: `Vue.use()` returns the Vue instance, therefore you can chain them: `Vue.use(BootstrapVue).use(VueAnalytics, { id: 'UA-12345678-9' }).use(SomeOtherPlugin)`.

Comment: @tao why is this not documented anywhere?

Comment: I don't know the answer to that question. But the source code is one click away in any decent IDE.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Don't overthink it. Just call `Vue.use` twice.

```
Vue.use(BootstrapVue);

Vue.use(VueAnalytics, {
    id: 'UA-12345678-9'
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
import BootstrapVue from 'bootstrap-vue'
import VueAnalytics from 'vue-analytics'

[BootstrapVue, VueAnalytics].forEach((x) => Vue.use(x));
```

This is what I usually use.

Answer (score 1):

I will use:

```
const useArray = [Bootstrap-Vue, Vue Analytics];
useArray.forEach((item)=>{
  Vue.use(item)
})
```

Comment: This solution doesn't account for potential settings/options that might need to be applied for each plugin (like the `id` in the question). But still a decent solution if that's not a concern.